# Serverless Framework ignoring "authorizer" block in lambda-proxy setup

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless

We have a `serverless.yml` that creates a lambda proxy in APIGateway.

I have seen several ways to attach a cognito user pool authorizer to the lambda proxy, but none of them work. In every case, the result is that no auth is set up on the either the Proxy or Proxy+. (As in, in the API Gateway console, "Auth" always reads "NONE".)

Example:

```
    events:
      - http: ANY /
        integration: lambda-proxy
        authorizer:
          type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
          authorizerId:
            Ref: CognitoUserPoolAuthorizer
      - http: ANY {proxy+}
        integration: lambda-proxy
        authorizer:
          arn: ${self:custom.userPools.arnBase}/${self:custom.userPools.ids.${self:custom.stage}}
          # The above results in the format: "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-west-2:<account_id>:userpool/us-west-2_<user_pool_id>"
```

You can see above that I'm trying two different methods to accomplish the same task. (Let's try throwing science at the wall and see what sticks.) 
Both methods are documented in different places [by the serverless framework](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/), but neither are documented with respect to lambda proxy, so I'm not sure if there's an undocumented difference.

In the first method (using `Ref` on a resource), the resource is correctly created, but no auth is attached to the endpoint. (I didn't include the resource block here, because that is working as expected.) The second method has the same effect (but no authorizer is created).

Our serverless framework version is 1.52, which meets the requirement stated in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664708/cognito-user-pool-authorizer-with-serverless-framework).

I have also tried with `integration` set to `lambda`, or with that line absent altogether. The result is the same in all cases.

I *have* gotten this to work by manually selecting the authorizer through the console, but we're trying to eliminate these manual steps.

What are we missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very quick glance, it looks like the indentation of your `serverless.yml` file may be off. Can you try again with a tab below the `http` array item?

Also, you'll need to remove the shorthand for method and path, and instead use them separately. The snippet below should work:

```
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
          integration: lambda-proxy
          authorizer:
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            authorizerId:
              Ref: CognitoUserPoolAuthorizer
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /{proxy+}
          integration: lambda-proxy
          authorizer:
            arn: ${self:custom.userPools.arnBase}/${self:custom.userPools.ids.${self:custom.stage}}
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got a bad indentation error. Nice thought, though. I would have loved for that to be the problem.

Comment: I see. Here is another example with what I believe is correct indentation:
https://github.com/johnf/serverless-cognito-demo/blob/master/serverless.yml

Does that work?

Comment: Ok, so this is correct, but not ONLY for indentation reasons!

It turns out that not only did it need to be indented more, but that we could not use the shorthand `-http: ANY /` -- indenting further AND changing to the multiline `method: ANY` and `path: /{proxy+}` did it. If you amend your answer to include that sugestion, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Yup, I noticed it immediately after posting the comment and amended it.

Thanks! Glad I could help.